# Can you play Age of Empires 2 multiplayer between PC and Mac?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings

My brother and I have a PC and a Mac, and we want to play *Age of Empires 2*.  Is the multiplayer compatible between the two?

Comment: Are you asking about AOE2 *only* or any AOE?

Comment: It's really strict about having the same version when you play PC/PC, so unless the Mac verson was kept exactly in line with the PC version then I doubt it.

Comment: i am asking about aoe2 gold edition. actually it does not matter. the conquerors or aoe2 age of kings or simple aoe2

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can play AoE2 over a LAN with a Mac and a PC.

Comment: Any gotchas or things to be concerned about? Or does it work flawlessly?

Comment: Can you open this a little bit. How we will able to play mulitplayer? Is there specific version of AoE2?