# How do I play Age of Empires 2: Age of Kings multiplayer with a mac and a pc?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings

I'm not sure what the problem is. I just can't find any games or connect to them. It works between two macs. There was a similar [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/44220/can-you-play-age-of-empires-2-multiplayer-between-pc-and-mac) claiming that it does work but not stating how.

Comment: I don't think they are compatible. Although that question was answered, he didn't actually give any way how to and it wasn't accepted. See here: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090618174847AA6GlQM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not play them together:

> Multiplayer matches between Mac OS and Windows clients do not work as the game version is different on each operating system. This leads to a version mismatch error when attempting to join a match. The current Mac version 1.0.5 is only in sync with the 1.12 Windows version, when it needs to be in sync the Windows version 1.13.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_Empires_III)

Although that is from Age of Empires 3 I think that it's safe to assume the most recent release would be the more likely to accomodate cross platform matchups. Not to mention **EVERY** thread online says that you can't do it.

You could run Windows off your MAC and then play them against each other, but this would involve quite a bit of effort.

Comment: Indeed not what I was hoping for but thanks! :)

Comment: Sorry my friend. Even found a few posts from the guy who made GameRanger (the multiplayer client) that you can't play cross-platform